# Custom Exception throw in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java

I Want to create some custom exception in my spring boot application using `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler` but I can get exception details as a json

I tried every thing could not find the solution. `ErrorDetails` is a class where i used setter and getter and `StringNotFoundException` is class which extends Exception

```
    @ControllerAdvice()
    public class RestExceptionHandler {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(StringNotFoundException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorDetails handleNotFoundException(StringNotFoundException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {

        ErrorDetails ed = new ErrorDetails();
        ed.setErrorCode("10000");
        ed.setErrorMessage(ex.getMessage());
        ed.setErrorDescription("Try");
        ed.setPort(environment.getProperty("local.server.port"));
        ed.setUrl(request.getRequestURI().toString());
        System.out.println(ed + "****************");
        return ed;}}
```

In controller I using this:

```
if (companyList.isEmpty()) {
throw new StringNotFoundException();
            }
```

Exception details shows on console but i could not get json format

> com.ffi.financialcompany.exception.StringNotFoundException

Comment: i don't think so `handleNotFoundException` method gets executed

Comment: Yes its not executed.. I debug that ..but don't understand the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try making RestExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler.

ResponseEntityExceptionHandler is a class used by Spring framework to throw Exceptions. I think you should extend that class in order to work this out.

```
    @ControllerAdvice()
    public class RestExceptionHandler extends  ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    ....
```